# How to make events between backgroundworker threads execute in their own context

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, delegates, backgroundworker

This question was asked 11 years ago but the answers all assumed Winform/WPF.  I'd like to ask it again but clarify these are two backgroundworker threads.

I'd like to have two Threads. Let's call them:

- Thread A (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is 16)
- Thread B (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is 18);

Thread A fires an event and Thread B listens to this event.  When the Thread B event listener (delegate) is executed, it's executed with the Thread A's context (16).

What I'd like to do is be able to fire event in Thread A (16) and the delegate code execute under the context of Thread B (18).

From what I've seen there is no SynchronizationContext available in this scenario.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What kind of application do you have in mind? Console application?

Comment: It's a windows service running multiple plug-ins.  There is a thread-daemon which subscribes to events from other components.  I had a bug whereby one of those components died (it's never meant to exit) due to a bug in the delegate.  This struck me as odd because that's equivalent to the above that a bug in Thread B caused Thread A to exit.  So from a error handling point of view I'd prefer the thread daemon delegate methods operated in the context of the daemon (thread B #18).

Comment: There is no "Thread B event listener". The event listener may have been attached by Thread B, but there's nothing that remembers that. It's just an event listener and it runs on whatever thread the event is raised on.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The question was how to have the thread firing the event marshal the data and execute in another thread's context (thread b).   What I was really looking for was an equivalent pattern I've oft used in WinForms whereby:
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(() => MyEvent(myData));
Except there is no SynchronizationContext to marshal the call from one thread to another between 2 worker threads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As usual when I find an elegant solution to a problem I look at it and wonder why it didn’t just pour out of my head that way?  Sadly it took me a good while to get there but I’m happy with the result and how it could be made reusable with little effort.

I hope it’s a useful and interesting read:

https://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2021/04/15/thread-synchronization-between-worker-threads/

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - so that you could take advantage of the `EventLoopScheduler` class. This class creates a single thread that you can schedule tasks on in a variety of ways.

Given `private EventLoopScheduler _eventLoopScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();` I can do this to run code on the specific thread:

```
IDisposable scheduled =
    _eventLoopScheduler
        .Schedule(() =>
        {
            /* Run code in the `EventLoopScheduler` */
        });
```

You can even schedule events in the future and make them recurring. To cancel scheduled code you can call `scheduled.Dispose()`.

Now, given `private event EventHandler MyEvent;` I can do this with the Rx libraries:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
            h => this.MyEvent += h,
            h => this.MyEvent -= h)
        .ObserveOn(_eventLoopScheduler)
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            /* Run code in the `EventLoopScheduler` */
        });
```

This subscribes to the event and pushes execution to the thread created by the `EventLoopScheduler`.

When you're done call `subscription.Dispose()` and `_eventLoopScheduler.Dispose()` to clean up and allow the thread to end.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar in the end.  I defined a Queue<Action> in my thread daemon which receives events from other threads.  OnDoWork defines a while loop which deuques and invokes actions then waits on a lock.  It also defines an Invoke method which grabs the same lock, enqueues an action, and pulses the lock.  This effectively marshalled the action from Thread A to Thread B's execution context.  However, I would have preferred to be able to return an IAsyncResult so Thread A could effectively JOIN to get the return value of the event delegate from Thread B.

Comment: I solved by IAsyncResult problem by enqueuing an object containing the data, delegate, and lock.  Same idea as before but instead of marshalling over just the Action to be invoked by the other thread (B) I'm sending the object allowing synchronization.  So caller (A) creates IAsyncResult object, passes to event, event enqueues object (InvokeRequired), pulses message lock, and returns.  Now we have option to join (EndInvoke) for result in Thread A.  Meanwhile Thread B awakes, dequeues object, invokes action, sets result, sets lock.  Thread A awakens and can get return result from object.

Comment: @codinglifestyle - Please post your answer as an answer.